# Best way for filtering within searched results

Tags: asp.net, search, paging

I am trying to refine search within the searched results based on rating.
But number of returned results is more than 1000.

So, we have to page them too, and user can sort them too based on rating.

Now, for prototyping I have stored those 1000 results in Session object.

But, is it a good idea. As there could be 1000s of queries, then Session variables would be higher.

Please suggest better / proven ways for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Viewstate instead of session if you stay on that page and not move data to another page

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest you to save `1000s records in session object`, as when you have more users on your website, your server will be out of memory.

You could use a Stored Procedure to get only the number of records that you want to show in a page.

Get an idea from these links:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CustomPagingStoredProc.aspx

[Stored Procedure for Custom Paging](http://www.tipsntracks.com/316/gridview-custom-paging-in-asp-net-3-5-with-sql-server-stored-procedure.html)